# C - Regarding the preprocessor declaration of a string

Tags: c, string, preprocessor

So I got this little bit of a program that I've got typed up from a textbook.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define string char* 


int main(void) {
    string a[] = { "I", "like", "to", "fight," },
    b[] = {"pinch,","and","bite."};

    printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], b[0], b[1], b[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

As it stands it throws the following errors:

```
exit status 1
main.c: In function 'main':

main.c:7:18: error: excess elements in char array initializer
  b[] = {"pinch,","and","bite."};

main.c:7:18: note: (near initialization for 'b')

main.c:7:24: error: excess elements in char array initializer
  b[] = {"pinch,","and","bite."};

main.c:7:24: note: (near initialization for 'b')
```

Obviously, the goal is to make this work. The book hints that, in the `#define` preprocessor, one single character can be added on to make it work. And, with the errors all centered around the `b` string, I thought it would be `b`. But it's not. Either that, or I'm putting the `b` in the wrong spot. My understanding of this problem is that, while it is creating enough space for the a string, it is not for the `b` string.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code expands into `char *a[]={...}, b[]={...};`. There is a missing asterisk in front of `b` (_the missing character_). Why don't you use `typedef`? Type definition via preprocessor is always a bad idea.

Comment: I think this is making `a` of type `char *[]` and `b` of type `char []`.

Comment: It's funny you ask, the original code does actually use a typedef, but the instructions ask to remove it, and move the declaration of the string(s) into the preprocessor. Personally, I don't like using #define in this context, but it's what the book wants.

Comment: I believe the compiler is treating `b` as a `char array` and not as a `char pointer`.

Comment: Perhaps the assignment wants you to learn this lesson?  And me, personally, I don't like using the comma operator partially because of things like this.

Comment: Stephen explains it below. It's a bit misleading to do `char* a, b` because the `*` binds to `a` but _not_ `b` (i.e. `char *a; char b;`). Although `char*` has become a common idiom, it really plays out as `char *`. Better to define as `char *`. Doing `*b` to fix it kinda defeats the purpose of the `#define`, so use a typedef or spell it out. Also, I _never_ use the comma operator in declarations to avoid this [hard to see] ambiguity. It's actually cleaner to keep the declarations separate [on separate lines].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you had

```
int *a, b;
```

You would probably quickly see that you have one int pointer and one int.  The same is happening with your code

```
string a[] = { "I", "like", "to", "fight," },
b[] = {"pinch,","and","bite."};
```

gets changed to

```
char* a[] = { "I", "like", "to", "fight," },
b[] = {"pinch,","and","bite."};
```

so you have one array of char pointers and one array of char.  The single char you need to add is `*` to make `b` an array of char pointers.

```
char* a[] = { "I", "like", "to", "fight," },
*b[] = {"pinch,","and","bite."};
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I got tunnel vision and thought it was gonna be in the preprocessor, but yea that does make sense. Thank you!